# Inverse quadratic norms

Tags: inequalities, quadratic-forms

The following problem seems easy at a first glance but I can't see the way to prove it. Actually I don't even know if it's true but it is assumed implicitly in a research paper.

Help highly appreciated.

Given two spd matrices $A$, $B$ with

$x^\top Ax \ge x^\top Bx$

then it follows that
$x^\top A^{-1}x \le x^\top B^{-1}x$.

Any ideas?

Comment: "spd" = "positive semi-definite"??

Comment: @SamHopkins - no, I think "PosiTive Semi-Definite" would be PTSD. I think SPD is Symmetric Positive-Definite.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: ah, okay, I thought it could be based on French or something but that makes more sense. Anyways perhaps the question-asker can clarify.

Comment: @SamHopkins - Indeed, the OP should clarify. I just have the weakness of not being able to resist a joke.

Comment: spd = symmetric positive definite.

Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposed result holds **true**.

I am assuming throughout that $spd$ means [*symmetric positive definite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) and that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are $n$-by-$n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ for some $n > 0$.

Indeed, since $B = P^{\top}P$ for some $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ by hypothesis (see e.g., [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_bilinear_form)), we can assume, without loss of generality, that $B = I_n$, the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix.

Let us assume that $A - B = A - I_n$ is [positive semi-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) and let $O$ be an $n$-by-$n$ orthogonal matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $O^{\top}AO$ is diagonal. Clearly, the matrices $O^{\top}(A - I_n)O$ and $O^{\top}(I_n - A ^{-1})O$ are also diagonal. Conjugating then both sides of the identity $A - I_n = A(I_n - A^{-1})$ by $O$, yields immediately that $I_n - A^{-1}$ is positive semi-definite (check the signs of diagonal coefficients on both sides), hence the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask how you come to the conclusion? We have that $O$ also diagonalizes $A(I_n -A^{-1})$ and that this term is spd. Why is then $(I_n-A^{-1})$ also spd?

Comment: got it - thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

The result follows from operator monotonicity of inverse over symmetric positive definite matrices, i.e., $A \succeq B \Rightarrow A^{-1} \preceq B^{-1}$, which is a special case of the Löwner-Heinz theorem. See for example, [Theorem 2.6 here](http://www.ueltschi.org/AZschool/notes/EricCarlen.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. This is a bit to abstract for my taste, but it probably also proves the statement.